# improper placement of dynamic figures when fig_caption=true in pdf_document

Tags: r, knitr

Knitr misplaces the output graphics when output format is pdf and fig_caption is set to true. Could you reproduce this problem?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "xxx"
date: "December 19, 2016"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        fig_caption: true
---

# section 1

## sub 1
some text

```{r, fig.cap="caption2"}
plot(10:1)
```

# section 2
````

the plot draws under section 2.
I have also filed an issue on [github repo](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1339) but no answer yet.